# How to create a new DataPointCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-visualization

I have difficulties with creating a new DataPointCollection.
I could just make a list of DataPoint but I think DataPointCollection offers some pretty good methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.aspx).
I tried to start defining a new DataPointCollection but those attempts lead to the error that there is no definition of the constructor regarding DataPointCollection.

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
DataPointCollection foo = new DataPointCollection();
DataPointCollection bar = new DataPointCollection(){};
```

Furtermore i cannot write;

```
DataPointCollection foo;
foo.AddXY(5,5);
```

because i can't use a not assigned local variable

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating `DataPointCollection`? Why not just `List<DataPoint>`?

Comment: I would like to use the methods of DataPointCollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.aspx)

Comment: hmm, but what I understand is internally `DataPointCollection` class holds the reference of `ChartControl` itself in order to respond for `ResumeUpdate`, `suspendUpdate`, `Add` and `Remove` etc, So it is pointless to create a `DataPointCollection` without a series or ChartControl

Comment: ok thanks. i have a chart...
Then I'll define the list of DataPoint and add them later